# Can't get to configure xdebugger on Windows 7 Machine

Tags: php

I have tried for hours to configure xdebugger for php but with no result :s,

I have a windows 7 OS, 64 bit, XAMPP installed with 5.4.7 PHP version therefor i downloaded from xdebug.org this version PHP 5.4 VC9 TS (64 bit) and put under **ext** directory (I am not sure if TS is right version as my phpinfo() have Thread Safe enabled.

The next step I added these line on php.ini which is located under **php** directory folder

php.ini now looks with these lines added:

```
    ;Added by me
    zend_extension_ts="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"
    xdebug.remote_enable = 1
    xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
    xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
    xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

I restart my pc and try to look to localhost and phpinfo() xdebugger does not appear yet :s

Would you suggest me anything or let me know if I have forgoten something in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have here a windows 7 64 maching and xdebug works like a charm. And I also have php 5.4.7 running.

if I go to my php.ini file it looks like:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 10;
```

I disabled the other options because I did not need them, but xdebug works even with them so that is not the point

I have [php_xdebug.dll](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oskxlx4mtlyd3wn/php_xdebug.dll) this file in my extension and it works.

If I look at my PHPinfo it says `Thread Safety  enabled`. So I guess you should try the other setup and if that not works look at the attached file.

Comment: dudee, u saved my life :D, ur xdebug file worked